# How to implement digital right management in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-5.4, drm

I am building an app for content distribution like iTunes and Amazon musics. i would like to implement digital right management on the contents like audio, videos etc to avoid piracy. How will i go about it. I am using Vue Js as my Front-End and Laravel as my API Back-End.

Comment: If you want full DRM you need a DRM service or server - you can do less secure, but maybe adequate for your needs, clearkey DRM encryption yourself - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46473146/334402

Comment: okay, thanks for your reply @mick, which service or server do you suggest me to purchase

Comment: I think you need to google them and investigate the alternatives to decide yourself. It would probably be useful to play with the clearkey also to get a better feel for the integrations.